# nginx hotlink special redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, hotlinking

First, sorry for my english.

I try do some special hotlink prevent on my website.

For example i have images on

http://s1.example.com/i/img_123.jpg
And if someone use this image on your own website in code, not redirect. But if he visit directly this image, nginx redirect to 
http://example.com/z/img_123.jpg <- not image but page with html code, etc.

How can I get it?

Comment: I don't get why would you like to redirect to an image but return an html.

Comment: I like to redirect to html with this image + other content, ads. etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
server {                                                 
  root /var/www;

  index index.htm;
  server_name s1.sitename;

  location ~ \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ {
    valid_referers blocked example.com;
    if ($invalid_referer) { 
      # returning an htm. You can replace this with an image
      return 403 /error.htm;
    }
  }
}
```

## EDIT - Second version of my answer

```
location ~ \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ {
  valid_referers blocked example.com;
  if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403 /error.htm;
  }

  # If not invalid. we make a URL rewrite
  rewrite i/(.*) http://www.example.com/z/$1 redirect;

  # this is a suggestion. Enable expire. It's static data, and you should not
  # waste resources serving these files every single time.
  expires 30;

  break;
}
```

Comment: Hello, not what I meant.

It's should not block views with referers. But thanks for answer.

Comment: It doesn't block everything. It allows traffic from sites on the list "valid_referers". You may add more domains or epxressions like "*.example.com" to allow any subdomain.

Answer (score -1):

I have answer for my problem :)

```
if ($http_referer = '') {
    rewrite i/(.*) http://www.example.com/z/$1 redirect;
    expires off;
    break;
}
```

Comment: What you are doing here is redirecting clients with not 'referal' to the other site. Clients coming from any other site will be allowed. I think you should update update $http_referer with something more specific.